# Buggy Javascript PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-form

I am currently working on a PDF with custom calculations.

Below is some part of the code which is giving me various issues:

```
var WidowerValue = getField("WidowerAllow").value;  
var WidowerAnswer = getField("WidowsEnti").value;  
var WidowerChildren = getField("under18Total01").value;  

var Child01Benefit = WidowerChildren * 1620;  
var Child01Allowance = WidowerChildren * 1534;  


if(WidowerAnswer == "Yes"){  
  if(Child01Benefit != 0 && Child01Allowance !=0){  
  event.value = WidowerValue + Child01Benefit + Child01Allowance;  
  }else{  
    event.value = WidowerValue;  
  }  

}  
else if(WidowerAnswer == "No"){  
  if(Child01Benefit !=0){  
    event.value = Child01Benefit;  
    }  
}
```

This is in a textfield which values change dependent on the conditions met. It works(sometimes), I usually have to click into the box and delete the wrong value it entered and then it will show the correct calculation. Other times it doesn't actually add the values just joins them together e.g instead of 5 + 5 = 10(correct) it will place 5+5 = 55(wrong), this again is corrected when i manually remove the wrong value.

Can anyone offer insight into why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: You probably just need to consistently ensure that the values you get back are really numbers. Simplest way: `+getField("WidowerAllow").value` - the `+` unary operator will force the value to be interpreted as a number. (If it's not a number, the result is `NaN`.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have set all the related boxes to Number format and also added the +getField to the code, it is calculating correctly but not updating until i delete the current value and let it recalculate.

Comment: Do you have other calculations in the form, and do the values you are working with depend on the result of other calculations? If so, check the Calculation Order and adjust it accordingly. In order to have full control over such dependencies, it is best practice to consolidate all calculations into one single script, and assign it to a (hidden, readonly) field not even involved in the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

In JS + is an operator to concat strings and do an addition of integer.

String + String is a String concatination. 
Number + Number is an addition of Numbers.

```js
var string = '5';

function concat() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = string + string;
}

function addition() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Number(string) + Number(string);
}
```

```html
<div id='result'>Click a Button</div>
<button onclick="concat();">String concat</button>
<button onclick="addition();">Addition</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have set all the related boxes to Number format and also added the +getField to the code, it is calculating correctly but not updating until i delete the current value and let it recalculate.